# Sort data using partial information in each cell using Excel or R

Tags: r, excel, sorting

My dataset looks like followings:

```
S(3): 99.5   S(4): 7.0   S(5): 42.9  S(6): 42.9  S(7): 6.6   S(9): 1.1   S(13): 0.0     
S(1): 49.7   S(3): 49.7  S(5): 0.5   S(11): 0.2  S(14): 16.4     
S(1): 17.4   S(3): 65.2  S(5): 17.4  S(11): 0.2  S(14): 6.5  T(15): 86.7    
S(1): 0.0    S(3): 100.0                    
S(1): 50.0   S(3): 50.0  T(7): 0.0   T(10): 0.0  S(19): 0.0  S(21): 0.0
```

I want to arrange this as a descending order of the value coming after colon. For example, for the first row:

S(3): **99.5**   S(5): **42.9**   S(6): **42.9**  S(4): **7.0**   S(7): **6.6**  S(9): **1.1**   S(13): **0.0**

If I want to reorder data like this for the every row, how can I do this using Excel or R?
Or if it's complicate, can I ask to extract 3 highest value in each row? For example, for the first row, it will be:

```
S(3): 99.5  S(5): 42.9   S(6): 42.9
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: I don't recognize the data format. If it's an R data frame, could you please provide the output of ```dput(dataFrameName)```

Comment: What is the delimiter? Looks like TAB?

Comment: For example, S(3): 99.5 is in one cell. And, each line indicates the same row.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it in R:

```
v <- readLines(n = 5)
S(3): 99.5   S(4): 7.0   S(5): 42.9  S(6): 42.9  S(7): 6.6   S(9): 1.1   S(13): 0.0     
S(1): 49.7   S(3): 49.7  S(5): 0.5   S(11): 0.2  S(14): 16.4     
S(1): 17.4   S(3): 65.2  S(5): 17.4  S(11): 0.2  S(14): 6.5  T(15): 86.7    
S(1): 0.0    S(3): 100.0                    
S(1): 50.0   S(3): 50.0  T(7): 0.0   T(10): 0.0  S(19): 0.0  S(21): 0.0 
(l <- lapply(strsplit(v, "\\s{2,}"), function(x) {
  x[order(-as.numeric(sub("[A-Z]\\(\\d+\\): ([0-9.]+)", "\\1", x)))]
}))
# [[1]]
# [1] "S(3): 99.5" "S(5): 42.9" "S(6): 42.9" "S(4): 7.0"  "S(7): 6.6"  "S(9): 1.1"  "S(13): 0.0"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "S(1): 49.7"  "S(3): 49.7"  "S(14): 16.4" "S(5): 0.5"   "S(11): 0.2" 
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "T(15): 86.7" "S(3): 65.2"  "S(1): 17.4"  "S(5): 17.4"  "S(14): 6.5"  "S(11): 0.2" 
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "S(3): 100.0" "S(1): 0.0"  
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] "S(1): 50.0" "S(3): 50.0" "T(7): 0.0"  "T(10): 0.0" "S(19): 0.0" "S(21): 0.0"
sapply(l, paste, collapse = "   ")
# [1] "S(3): 99.5   S(5): 42.9   S(6): 42.9   S(4): 7.0   S(7): 6.6   S(9): 1.1   S(13): 0.0"
# [2] "S(1): 49.7   S(3): 49.7   S(14): 16.4   S(5): 0.5   S(11): 0.2"                       
# [3] "T(15): 86.7   S(3): 65.2   S(1): 17.4   S(5): 17.4   S(14): 6.5   S(11): 0.2"         
# [4] "S(3): 100.0   S(1): 0.0"                                                              
# [5] "S(1): 50.0   S(3): 50.0   T(7): 0.0   T(10): 0.0   S(19): 0.0   S(21): 0.0"
```